# Второе модальное окно не закрывается

Tags: javascript, html, css

Второе модальное окно не закрывается, при повторном клике на кнопку закрытия.
Функция закрытия применяется к первому div, второй остается. Как можно выйти из этой ситуации?)

```
<style>
    /*форма обратной связи */   


    /* The Modal (background) */

    .modal {
      display: none;
      /* Hidden by default */
      position: fixed;
      /* Stay in place */
      z-index: 1;
      /* Sit on top */
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      /* Full width */
      height: 100%;
      /* Full height */
      overflow: auto;
      /* Enable scroll if needed */
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      /* Fallback color */
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      /* Black w/ opacity */
      -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
      /* Fade in the background */
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
      animation-name: fadeIn;
      animation-duration: 0.4s
    }

    .modal2 {
      display: block;
      /* Hidden by default */
      position: fixed;
      /* Stay in place */
      z-index: 1;
      /* Sit on top */
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      /* Full width */
      height: 100%;
      /* Full height */
      overflow: auto;
      /* Enable scroll if needed */
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      /* Fallback color */
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      /* Black w/ opacity */
      -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
      /* Fade in the background */
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
      animation-name: fadeIn;
      animation-duration: 0.4s
    }


    /* Modal Content */

    .modal-content {

      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #fefefe;
      width: 25%;
      -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
      animation-name: slideIn;
      animation-duration: 0.4s;
      animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
      margin: 15% auto;
      position: relative;
        padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    }


    .modal-content2 {

      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #fefefe;
      width: 25%;
      -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
      animation-name: slideIn;
      animation-duration: 0.4s;
      animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
      margin: 15% auto;
      position: relative;
        padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    }


    /* The Close Button */

    .close {
      color: white;
      float: right;
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }


    .newModalclose {
      color: black;
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .newModalclose:hover,
    .newModalclose:focus {
      color: red;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .modal-header {
      padding: 2px 16px;
      background-color: #5cb85c;
      color: white;
    }

    .modal-body {
      padding: 2px 16px;
    }

    .modal-footer {
      padding: 2px 16px;
      background-color: #5cb85c;
      color: white;
    }


    /* Add Animation */

    @-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
      from {
        bottom: -300px;
        opacity: 0
      }
      to {
        bottom: 0;
        opacity: 1
      }
    }

    @keyframes slideIn {
      from {
        bottom: -300px;
        opacity: 0
      }
      to {
        bottom: 0;
        opacity: 1
      }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
      from {
        opacity: 0
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }

    @keyframes fadeIn {
      from {
        opacity: 0
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }

        </style>




<a class="myBtn">test</a>
  <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">



        <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">

              <span class="close">&times;</span>

            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Получить спецпредложение</p>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
                    <div class="button_small_screen">
                        <input id="myBtn2" class="button2_ourstyle" id="send-button" style="width:100%" type="submit" value="Получить">

                    </div>
            </div>
          </div>





<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var myBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('myBtn');
var close = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

var newModalBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn2');
/*
А это в цикле прокруциваем те элементы которыми мы открываем модал окно
и обработчик события который открывет окно
*/
for (var i = 0; i < myBtn.length; i++) {
  myBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    openModalWindow();
  })
}
// это обработчик события, который в нутри этой функции выполнят ту функцию 
//которая закрывает окно модальное
close.addEventListener('click', function() {
  closeModalWindow();
})

//это функция, которая открывает окно
function openModalWindow() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

//это функция, которая закрывает окно
function closeModalWindow() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

newModalBtn.onclick = () => {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        var newModalWindow = document.createElement('div');



        newModalWindow.innerHTML =
            "<div id=\"for_hidden_ident\"  class=\"modal2\">" +
            "<div class=\"modal-content2\">\n" +
            "            <span class=\"newModalclose\">&times;</span>\n" +
            "        <div class=\"modal-body\">\n" +
            "            <p>Ваша заявка отправлена. </p>\n" +
            "        </div>\n" 
            "</div>\n"          

        document.body.appendChild(newModalWindow);
        newModalWindow.style.display = "block";
        var newModalclose = document.getElementsByClassName('newModalclose')[0];

        // это обработчик события, который в нутри этой функции выполнят ту функцию 
//которая закрывает окно модальное
newModalclose.addEventListener('click', function() {
  closeModalWindow2();
})

//это функция, которая закрывает окно
function closeModalWindow2() {
  newModalWindow.style.display =  "none";

}
setTimeout(() => newModalWindow.hidden = true, 4000)

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Я боюсь никто в этой простыне разбираться не будет. Поправьте вопрос, разделите его на html и js файлы. Удалите css, вам же плевать на вёрстку здесь. Выделите основную функцию, в которой проблема.

Answer (score 0):

В момент, когда вы создаете второе модальное окно, надо навесить ему событие реакции ан клик.
Получается что вы создали окно, но события клика не навешено.
После

```
document.body.appendChild(newModalWindow);
```

добавьте навешиваение события

```
 close.addEventListener('click', function() {
  closeModalWindow();
})
```